# C/C++ call-graph utility for Windows platform

Tags: c++, c, winapi, utility, call-graph

I have a large 95% C, 5% C++ Win32 code base that I am trying to grok.

What modern tools are available for generating call-graph diagrams for C or C++ projects?

Comment: +1 because I want to see the answers to this too.

Comment: You can try cppdepend(http://www.cppdpend.com) which gives the possibility to generate graphs for very large projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried SourceInsight's call graph feature?

- http://www.sourceinsight.com/docs35/ae1144092.htm

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)  and [codeviz](http://www.skynet.ie/~mel/projects/codeviz/) ?

Doxygen is normally used as a documentation tool, but it can generate call graphs for you with the [CALL_GRAPH/CALLER_GRAPH](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) options turned on.

Wikipedia lists a bunch of other [options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph) that you can try.

Comment: More details about doxygen solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34063485/5951077

Comment: Doxygen does not generate callgraphs upon actually run time environments.

Answer (score 3):

Good old cflow works fine for C. See [here](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/cflow.tar.gz) for an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Any decent static analysis tool should have this functionality (as well as all the other stuff that such tools do).  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) has a good list of such tools.

Another group of tools that may be worth checking out are coverage tools.  The call graph generated by the coverage tool will contain only the calls that actually take place during a run of the program.  Initially this may be more helpful to you than a full call graph.  I'm unable to make any suggestions on this for Windows, but for linux projects I highly recommend [gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) and [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php).