# Source Code Browser

Tags: c++, ide

I'm looking for a piece of relatively simple software to browse large C++ project. What I would like is something that is somewhere between a simple text editor and a full-blown IDE like Eclipse. I would like syntax highlighting, a way to see all classes/methods defined in a file, a way to find where a particular method is called from and where a variable is declared/defined.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is a full-blown IDE not suitable?

Comment: It might be a matter of opinion, but I would call everything that fulfills your requirements a full blown IDE (not necessarily a nice one depending on what other features it has, but still).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390707/c-source-code-comprehension-tools/1317763 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271513/c-code-visualization/1274445

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know where a particular method is called from, you are going to require some heavy lifting from the IDE. Intellisense like features always compile the code under the hood to give you the benefits of finding where code is called, and where it is defined. I don't consider that lightweight really.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Geany](http://geany.org/).  It's a fairly light text editor with a gentle learning curve that has syntax highlighting, and at least a way to see what's defined in a file; it may have the rest available, too.  And it's available for multiple operating systems, since you don't specify.