# C: dependency analysis of functions

Tags: c

Is there a tool where I can give a file + function name as an input and it gives me all functions the given function depends on and the same for all the found functions, and so on within my codebase?

Something like this would help a lot in extracting functionality from existing codebases.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nll) with [dot](http://www.graphviz.org) to create a call graph -- it should work fine even without doxygen annotations in the comments.

See some samples of it [here](http://images.google.com/images?q=doxygen+call+graph).

Answer (score 0):

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245979/c-c-call-graph-utility-for-windows-platform).

Answer (score 0):

Source Navigator is a free tool that includes this functionality:

http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a standalone tool that will do this.  However it is a supported feature of certain IDE's such as Source Insight

- http://www.sourceinsight.com/